# Regarding the issue of a white background when customizing the bottomBar of a Scaffold using compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

一、Below is the issue I encountered. When I clip the bottomBar of Scaffold, there is still a white background that I cannot remove.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juYm9.png)

二、Here is a portion of my code first.

```
@Composable
fun HomePage(
    mainActions: MainActions,
    homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel(),
) {
    val navCtrl = rememberNavController()
    Scaffold(
        Modifier.navigationBarsPadding(),
        backgroundColor = Color.Red,
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavigation(homeViewModel,
                onTapBottom = {
                    navigatorTo(navCtrl, it)
                })
        }) { innerPadding ->
        NavHost(
            navCtrl,
            startDestination = NavigationRoute.homeRoute,
            Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            composable(NavigationRoute.homeRoute) {
                OneFragment()
            }
            composable(NavigationRoute.widgetRoute) {
                val vieModel: MessageViewModel = viewModel()
                TwoFragment(mainActions, vieModel)
            }
            composable(NavigationRoute.settingRoute) {
                ThreeFragment(mainActions)
            }
        }
    }
}


//自定义裁剪部分
//背景动画
@Composable
private fun BottomBarAnimalBgView(indexValue: Float) {
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(70.dp), onDraw = {
        drawIntoCanvas { canvas ->
            val paint = Paint()
            paint.color = Color(0xFF108888)//Color(0XFF0DBEBF)
            paint.style = PaintingStyle.Fill
            //先固定分为三等分
            val widthOfOne = size.width / 3
            //每一个弧度的中心控制点
            val centerWidthOfOneX = widthOfOne / 2
            //弧度端口到两遍ONewidth距离
            val marginLeftAndRight = centerWidthOfOneX / 1.6f

                val controllerX = centerWidthOfOneX / 6f

                val keyAnimal = widthOfOne * indexValue
                canvas.save()
                paint.asFrameworkPaint().setShadowLayer(
                    15f,
                    5f,
                    -6f,
                    Color(0xFF108888).toArgb()
                )
                canvas.drawCircle(Offset(centerWidthOfOneX + keyAnimal, 0f), 60f, paint)

            val path = Path().apply {
                moveTo(0f, 0f)
                lineTo(marginLeftAndRight / 2 + keyAnimal, 0f)
                cubicTo(
                    marginLeftAndRight + keyAnimal,
                    0f,
                    centerWidthOfOneX - (centerWidthOfOneX - controllerX) / 2f + keyAnimal,
                    size.height / 3f,
                    centerWidthOfOneX + keyAnimal,
                    size.height / 2.6f
                )
                cubicTo(
                    centerWidthOfOneX + (centerWidthOfOneX - controllerX) / 2f + keyAnimal,
                    size.height / 2.6f,
                    widthOfOne - (marginLeftAndRight) + keyAnimal,
                    0f,
                    widthOfOne - marginLeftAndRight / 2 + keyAnimal,
                    0f
                )
                lineTo(size.width, 0f)
                lineTo(size.width, size.height)
                lineTo(0f, size.height)
                close()
            }

            canvas.drawPath(path, paint)

            //裁剪
            val clipPath = Path().apply {
            moveTo(0f, 0f)
            lineTo(marginLeftAndRight / 2 + keyAnimal, 0f)
            cubicTo(
                marginLeftAndRight + keyAnimal,
                0f,
                centerWidthOfOneX - (centerWidthOfOneX - controllerX) / 2f + keyAnimal,
                size.height / 3f,
                centerWidthOfOneX + keyAnimal,
                size.height / 2.6f
            )
            cubicTo(
                centerWidthOfOneX + (centerWidthOfOneX - controllerX) / 2f + keyAnimal,
                size.height / 2.6f,
                widthOfOne - (marginLeftAndRight) + keyAnimal,
                0f,
                widthOfOne - marginLeftAndRight / 2 + keyAnimal,
                0f
            )
            lineTo(size.width, 0f)
            close()
            }
            canvas.clipPath(clipPath,ClipOp.Difference)
        }
    })
}
```

三、However, in Flutter, clipping can remove this background.

If the issue does not occur outside the Scaffold, it is likely caused by the default background color of the bottom navigation bar in Scaffold. Trying to override this default color in the Scaffold may solve the problem.

四、Below is the link to my code:

[ComposeUnit](https://github.com/luhenchang/ComposeUnit.git)

I tried without using Scaffold and the bottomBar works normally.